# ViewStub switch between layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout

i have a mainlayout with a viewstub and a couple of buttons.
depending on the button that the user touch the viewstub will be inflated with a different Layout (just like tabs).

is there a way to perform that?
is there any other way of do that(without using tabpanel)?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple viewstub in your xml file and can show the one you want against each button click and hide others.